# Fill up form in Word/Pdf

Tags: c#, pdf, printing, ms-word, preview

What I want to accomplish is a fill up form or a registration form for a hotel in word or pdf file. It's like after filling up name text box and clicking next another text box will appear. 
And also it needs to have a preview before printing. If possible, showing the preview simultaneously.

I really want to know where to start or if there is any, sample would be great.

Comment: I would use another approach: a form (winform/webform/whatever) to enter data (you can make it to show all fields at once or only needed,  or show new when previous is filled, etc.), once data are **ready**, display preview which you can either confirm (print and perform additional job, to example, processing the order) or cancel. I would recommend to use [`iTextSharp`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) to generate PDF.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would approach this problem is using Web form data and after confirmation from the user i would generate the report straight away. I dont think manipulating Word document or PDF document is the best approach :

1. Check User Input using your web form
2. Generate the Word or PDF document on your reporting server[Connect to it using WCF for instance]
3. Give the link of the generated document to the user. It would be up to the user to print it or only view it in their browser.